# Undefined field is inserting into Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

[image]

From the image when i add 2 skill one extra feild is adding into the database:  id_job is 173.

[image]

Here my html form and Here my jquery append code:

```js
var skillcount=0;
$(".addSkills").click(function(){
 $('#jobSkills tr:last').after('<tr><td class="col-xs-4"><input placeholder="Enter or Type a letter to search skills" class="wp-form-control searchskill" count="'+skillcount+'" id="skill_'+skillcount+'_title" name="skill['+skillcount+'][title]" type="text" autocomplete="off"></td><td class="col-xs-4"><input placeholder="Should be 10 - 100" class="wp-form-control" count="'+skillcount+'" id="skill_'+skillcount+'_weightage" name="skill['+skillcount+'][weightage]" type="text" autocomplete="off"></td><td class="col-xs-4"><select class="wp-form-control" name="skill['+skillcount+'][type]"><option value="0">Select Test Type</option><option value="1">Practice Test</option><option value="2">Qualifying</option></select></td ><td class="col-xs-4"><input  class="selectGdSkill" type="checkbox" count="'+skillcount+'" id="skill['+skillcount+'][gdskill]" name="skill['+skillcount+'][gdskill]"></td> <td class="col-xs-4"> <input class="selectPiSkill" type="checkbox" count="'+skillcount+'" id="skill['+skillcount+'][piskill]" name="skill['+skillcount+'][piskill]"></td><td class="col-xs-2"><span class="removeSkill" id="'+skillcount+'" ><a style="color:red">Remove</a></span></td></tr>');
 skillcount++;
 //console.log(skillcount);
});
$("#jobSkills").on('click','.removeSkill',function(){
 console.log($(this).parent());
 $(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
 <h4>Skills Required</h4>
 <div class="col-md-10">
  <table id="jobSkills" class="col-lg-10" style="border:1px;">
   <tbody>
    <tr><td  class="col-xs-4"> Skill </td><td class="col-xs-4"> Weightage </td><td class="col-xs-4"> Test Type </td><td class="col-xs-4"> Assign to GD-Skill</td> <td class="col-xs-4">Assign to PI-Skill</td> </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
  <span class="text-center btn btn-danger addSkills">+ Add Skills</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

My Controller Code:

```
foreach($_POST["skill"] as $k=>$key)
{
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO r_job_skill (id_job,title,weightage,type,gdskill,piskill) values ('".$jobId."','".$key["title"]."','".$key["weightage"]."','".$key["type"]."','".$gdskill."','".$piskill."')");
}
```

Comment: Use input elements as hidden to get posted values on server.

Comment: is any relation there skillcount=0.?   can you give an example..

Comment: Are you submitting form through jquery or php ?

Comment: From is php action="job-controller.php" method="post"  but i am calling this skills with jquery.@Loading..

Comment: You can check `if(!empty($key))` on foreach. May be it's posting blank array

Comment: If your fields are empty at the time of submit you need to check that in PHP by using `empty()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below quoted text in comment/answer

"First of all if you want to add id_job from other table then you can take hidden input and set the value and post it in the Controller Code. Suggestion: if its not related with other table then I suggest to keep id_job field 'auto increment' with primary key and pass NULL in insert query.

Also check values are empty or not before you insert in database, so it prevents to save blank record in database. "

Comment: i will check in that way and let you know.